# Performance of nested yield in a tree

Tags: c#, performance, ienumerable, yield

I've got a tree-like structure. Each element in this structure should be able to return a Enumerable of all elements it is root to. Let's call this method `IEnumerable<Foo> GetAll()`. So if we have

```
     A  <-- topmost root
    / \ 
   /   \
  B     C
 / \   / \
D   E F   G
```

a call to `GetAll` on element `C` returns `{C, F, G}` (fixed order of elements would be nice, but is not needed). I guess everybody knew that already.

The current implementation of `GetAll` looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAll ()
{
    yield return this;

    foreach (Foo foo in MyChildren) {
        foreach (Foo f in foo.GetAll ()) {
            yield return f;
        }
    }
}
```

In an earlier implementation, I returned a List and added the child-foos using `List.AddRange()`.

My question is if the version using yield is correcly implemented or if it should be improved (esp. in terms of performance). Or is this just bad and I should stick to `List`s (or `ReadOnlyCollections`) instead?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's certainly not ideal in terms of performance - you end up creating a lot of iterators for large trees, instead of a single iterator which knows how to traverse efficiently.

Some blog entries concerning this:

- Wes Dyer: [All about iterators](http://blogs.msdn.com/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx)
- Eric Lippert: [Immutability in C#, part 6](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/18/immutability-in-c-part-six-a-simple-binary-tree.aspx)
- Eric again: [Immutability in C#, part 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/12/19/immutability-in-c-part-seven-more-on-binary-trees.aspx)

It's worth noting that F# has the equivalent of the proposed "`yield foreach`" with "`yield!`"

Answer (score 21):

You can improve performance if you unroll recurse to stack, so you will have only one iterator:

```
public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAll()
{
    Stack<Foo> FooStack = new Stack<Foo>();
    FooStack.Push(this);

    while (FooStack.Count > 0)
    {
        Foo Result = FooStack.Pop();
        yield return Result;
        foreach (Foo NextFoo in Result.MyChildren)
            FooStack.Push(NextFoo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, only one yielded iterator and one MyChildren iterator per node, while original solutions having one yielded iterator per node, and one MyChildren iterator per node, plus recursion.

Comment: Thank you, I actually used this design in my code. I'm still marking Jon's answer as accepted since his link contain the same idea and he posted earlier. Hope you don't mind. o,o

Comment: Having had to do similar types of implementation workarounds, I've found that `List<T>` ends up having a lot better performance than `Queue<T>` and `Stack<T>`. Also the ability to do `List<T>.AddRange(...)` is a lot faster than a `foreach(...) { Queue<T>Enqueue(...) }`.

Comment: @mckamey were you using `.Count()` on the `Queue<T>` implementation because that could also explain the difference with `List<T>`? Likewise if the internal arrays have to keep growing that would also explain the performance difference.

Comment: One thing to note about this approach is that it does not return items in the same order as the original implementation. It returns children in reverse order since the last child `Push`ed is the first one `Pop`ed. Using `Queue` instead of `Stack` results in breadth-first traversal of the tree.

Answer (score 2):

A better solution might be to create a visit method that recursively traverses the tree, and use that to collect items up.

Something like this (assuming a binary tree):

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public void Visit(Action<T> action)
    {
        action(this);
        left.Visit(action);
        right.Visit(action);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Foo> GetAll ()
    {
        var result = new List<T>();
        Visit( n => result.Add(n));
        return result;
    }
}
```

Taking this approach

- Avoids creating large numbers of nested iterators
- Avoids creating any more lists than necessary
- Is relatively efficient
- Falls down if you only need part of the list regularly

Comment: It also takes up O(n) space instead of O(1) space - so it's efficient in terms of computation but not memory.

Comment: You should use a foreach instead of just left and right. He didn't specify it's a btree.

Comment: Yes, any node contains 0+ children. But that's not too much of a difference anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, that looks fine.

Have a look at my [blog entry](http://xacc.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/tree-traversal-extension-methods/), it may be of some use  :)

Answer (score -2):

According to my prior experiences using yield is a lot more effective than creating a List.
If you're using .NET 3.5, this implementation should be fine. But don't forget the

```
yield break;
```

At the end. :-)

Comment: Um, why would you want yield break at the end in this case?

Comment: Why do you need this at the end? I thought that the enumerator automatically finished when the Enumerable method exited ...

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I misunderstood something regarding the use of yield. As I remember I got an error if I didn't close the method with yield break;. I'm sorry if I said something stupid! Gonna look into that matter...

Comment: Right, the IEnumator.MoveNext() automatically breaks if it gets out of scope. But it still shouldn't hurt using yield break, but you're right, it's not required.