# Why is this code for iterating over the DOM stupid slow?

Tags: c#, optimization, html-agility-pack

This is nested about 10 functions deep, so I'll just paste the relevant bits:

This line is really slow:

```
var nodes = Filter_Chunk(Traverse(), chunks.First());
```

Specifically, this chunk inside `Filter_Chunk` (pun not intended):

```
private static IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Filter_Chunk(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes, string selectorChunk)
{
    // ...
    string tagName = selectorChunk;
    foreach (var node in nodes)
        if (node.Name == tagName)
            yield return node;
```

There's nothing too complicated in there... so I'm thinking it must be the sheer number of nodes in `Traverse()` right?

```
public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Traverse()
{
    foreach (var node in _context)
    {
        yield return node;
        foreach (var child in Children().Traverse())
            yield return child;
    }
}

public SharpQuery Children()
{
    return new SharpQuery(_context.SelectMany(n => n.ChildNodes).Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element), this);
}
```

I tried finding `<h3>` nodes on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138803/wheres-the-bug-in-this-tree-traversal-code). There shouldn't be more than a couple thousand nodes, should there? Why is this taking many minutes to complete?

---

Actually, there's definitely a bug in here somewhere that is causing it to return more nodes than it should... [I forked the question to address the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138803/wheres-the-bug-in-this-tree-traversal-code)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Performance of nested yield in a tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043050/c-performance-of-nested-yield-in-a-tree)

Comment: I can't give you any sort of specific answer, but I can point you to an interesting article on Joelonsoftware.com  Down near the bottom Joel talks about the performance hit of using XML for large data sets.  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html

Comment: Just a guess: try to use a List<HtmlNode> instead of IEnumerable / yield and tell us if this helps. Reason for your problem might be the overhead of the state machine the compiler internally builds for indexers when using yield.

Comment: @Jon/Doc: You're both wrong. That might improve performance a bit (and I appreciate the suggestions... I'll implement it once I find the bug) -- but there actually *is* a bug in there somewhere. It's traversing the same nodes more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Traverse()
{
    foreach (var node in _context)
    {
        yield return node;
        foreach (var child in Children().Traverse())
            yield return child;
    }
}
```

This code looks strange to me. `Children()` is independent for `_context`, so it makes no sense to run over the children one time for each node in _context.

Comment: You're right. I was trying to re-use a function I already had. Will accept to close question :)