# Where's the bug in this tree traversal code?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

There's a bug in `Traverse()` that's causing it to iterate nodes more than once.

### Bugged Code

```
public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Traverse()
{
    foreach (var node in _context)
    {
        yield return node;
        foreach (var child in Children().Traverse())
            yield return child;
    }
}

public SharpQuery Children()
{
    return new SharpQuery(_context.SelectMany(n => n.ChildNodes).Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element), this);
}

public SharpQuery(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes, SharpQuery previous = null)
{
    if (nodes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("nodes");
    _previous = previous;
    _context = new List<HtmlNode>(nodes);
}
```

### Test Code

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var sq = new SharpQuery(@"
<a>
    <b>
        <c/>
        <d/>
        <e/>
        <f>
            <g/>
            <h/>
            <i/>
        </f>
    </b>
</a>");
        var nodes = sq.Traverse();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} nodes: {1}", nodes.Count(), string.Join(",", nodes.Select(n => n.Name)));
        Console.ReadLine();
```

### Output

> 19 nodes: #document,a,b,c,g,h,i,d,g,h,i,e,g,h,i,f,g,h,i

### Expected Output

> Each letter a-i printed once.

Can't seem to figure out where's it going wrong... `node.ChildNodes` *does* return just direct children, right? (from HtmlAgilityPack)

---

Full class (condensed) if you want to try and run it yourself.

```
public class SQLite
{
    private readonly List<HtmlNode> _context = new List<HtmlNode>();
    private readonly SQLite _previous = null;

    public SQLite(string html)
    {
        var doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        _context.Add(doc.DocumentNode);
    }

    public SQLite(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes, SQLite previous = null)
    {
        if (nodes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("nodes");
        _previous = previous;
        _context = new List<HtmlNode>(nodes);
    }

    public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Traverse()
    {
        foreach (var node in _context)
        {
            yield return node;
            foreach (var child in Children().Traverse())
                yield return child;
        }
    }

    public SQLite Children()
    {
        return new SQLite(_context.SelectMany(n => n.ChildNodes).Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element), this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did the debugger tell you?

Comment: @Oli: About what? Where am I supposed to put a break point? It's a logic error, not a crashing error.

Comment: @Mark: Not sure I understand.  Debuggers aren't just for diagnosing crashes!

Comment: Can you post the whole SharpQuery class?

Comment: @BFree: It's 675 lines and less than a quarter complete >.< If you really want I'll make a condensed one.

Comment: @Oli: No... but I still have no idea where I'd put a breakpoint. The debugger told me it was getting stuck in the traverse loop. What more can it possibly tell me that I don't already know?

Comment: @Mark: Well, can you not step through and see *why* it's getting stuck?  i.e. at what point does your algorithm behaviour diverge from what you were expecting?

Comment: @Oli: Why do I need the debugger to tell me that? I posted the output and expected output... it very clearly diverges after "c" (next letter should be "d"). And btw, I did use the debugger to locate and isolate the problem, but I find it more helpful to actually print the output than digging through a call stack and stepping back and forth to see what the heck is going wrong. Of course, you're right that the debugger could have told me `_context` contained the wrong values... had I thought to look there.

Comment: @Mark: Your output tells you when your *output* diverged (i.e. the symptom), it doesn't tell you where the *algorithm* diverged (i.e. the cause).  Really, the debugger should be your first port of call; it will help you isolate 90% of problems.  Posting your code here is essentially asking others to do your job for you (although on this occasion, someone did that successfully), and I'm afraid this just comes across as laziness.  Please learn to use a debugger effectively in future!

Comment: @Oli: It's 5 lines of code. I know it diverged somewhere in there, how much more specific can you get? And it's not being lazy. I did try solving the problem first, and I continued to try and solve it after I posted the question, and I didn't copy-paste the answers people gave me, I learned from them and then implemented a solution my way. People like doing this kind of stuff or they wouldn't be on the site, and they wouldn't have given me any answers. If they think I'm being lazy, they don't need to answer.

Comment: @Oli: I work solo, not in a big office full of peers. Unfortunately, StackOverflow is one of the only places I can come to ask questions and get help on these kinds of things. Anyway, you've made up your mind about how ineffectively I use the debugger so... there's not much more I can say.

Comment: @Mark: Again, by stepping through line-by-line (or perhaps call-by-call) until the contents of the variables no longer match your expectations.  That is the basic premise of debugging.  I'd understand your point if your dataset was millions of items, or if it took hours of runtime before the bug appeared, or you had complex I/O interaction, or if your app was multithreaded; these can be horrifically hard to debug.  But you have none of these!  IMHO, this site is not for "please fix my code"-type questions, but for knowledge-sharing.

Comment: @Oli: Bugs are a natural part of programming. So are algorithms. If you don't like to idea of me asking about a bug, then think of it as a "how do I write a tree traversal algorithm?". At least I've given a shot before I came here to ask. Original dataset *did* take many minutes to complete and the debugger was indeed useless... I had to chop it down to size. And all the data is in enumerables, which are hard to see. It will diverge on the "yield return node" statement specifically, because that's what gives the wrong output, but that's not what is causing the issue.

Comment: @Mark: My previous comments were not intended to be elitist put-downs, apologies if they came across this way.  But seriously, learning how to debug is one of the most powerful skills you can acquire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that everything goes according to plan as long as we're iterating over elements that don't have any sibling. As soon as we hit element `<c>`, things start going haywire. It's also interesting that `<c>`, `<d>` and `<e>` all think they contain `<f>`'s children.

Let's take a closer look at your call to `SelectMany()`:

```
_context.SelectMany(n => n.ChildNodes)
```

That iterates through the items in `_context` and *accumulates* the child nodes of each item. Let's have a look at `_context`. Everything should be okay, since it's a `List` of length `1`. Or is it?

I suspect your `SharpQuery(string)` constructor stores sibling elements inside the same list. In that case, `_context` may not be of length `1` anymore and, remember, `SelectMany()` *accumulates* the child nodes of each item in the list.

For example, if `_context` is a list containing `<c>`, `<d>`, `<e>` and `<f>`, only `<f>` has children, and `SelectMany()` is called once for each element, it will accumulate and return the children of `<f>` four times.

I think that's your bug.

**EDIT:** Since you've posted the full class, I don't have to guess anymore. Look at the sequence of operations when you iterate over `<b>` (iterators replaced by lists for better comprehension):

1. Call `Children()` on `<b>`, which returns `<c>`, `<d>`, `<e>` and `<f>`,
2. Call `Traverse()` on the resulting list:

   1. Call `Children()` on `<c>`, *but* `_context` actually contains `<c>`, `<d>`, `<e>` and `<f>`, not only `<c>`, so that returns `<g>`, `<h>` and `<i>`,
   2. Call `Children()` on `<d>`, same thing since `_context` is *the same* for *both* `<c>` and `<d>` (and `<e>`, and `<f>`),
   3. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: I just posted the string constructor... it only adds the document node to the context, and nothing else.

Comment: Your problem is that sibling nodes share the same `_context`, and that doesn't work well with `SelectMany()`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Well, that explains the bug. Thanks :)

Comment: You posted the same link twice ;)

Comment: Whoops, my bad :) Since you'll have to rewrite that, you might want to remove the yield return from your loop and to use e.g. [an item stack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/03/23/all-about-iterators.aspx) to avoid creating too many iterators. See the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043050/c-performance-of-nested-yield-in-a-tree).

Answer (score 3):

Children() is broken, it selects children of siblings as well. I'd rewrite to something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Traverse(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes)
{
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        yield return node;
        foreach (var child in Traverse(ChildNodes(node)))
            yield return child;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<HtmlNode> ChildNodes(HtmlNode node)
{
    return node.ChildNodes.Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element);
}


public SharpQuery(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes, SharpQuery previous = null)
{
    if (nodes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("nodes");
    _previous = previous; // Is this necessary?
    _context = new List<HtmlNode>(nodes);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! I don't like making the functions take in arguments, but you gave me the right idea.. thank you! And yes, _previous is necessary, it's used by other functions.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this be enough?

```
public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Traverse()
{
    foreach (var node in _context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
        yield return node;
        foreach (var child in Children().Traverse())
            {} //yield return child;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope... you're traversing the full tree but not returning any of the results beyond the first level. At any level deeper than the first one, you are yielding the correct nodes, but then not doing anything with them (they're not passed to the calling function, just to depth-1).

Comment: To be fair, the you used to have `Console.WriteLine(node.Name)` inside the IEnumerable. Now that it is outside you are correct.

Comment: @Scott: Well... that Console.WriteLine was just for debugging... I moved it outside to not confuse issues. But you're right.. I guess it would have produced the correct output in this case, but the point isn't to print it, it's to actually return it ;)

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly, but you can see the pattern is that once your stuff encounter the "/" of the "c", it start to consider the "g,h,i" to be part of every subsequent letter until it encounter the "/" of the "f".

Most likely you have an extra loop that you should get ride of.

Or for some reason, it doesnt compute correctly the "/>" parts.

Comment: It's not the self-closing nodes. I tried expanding them too. Where's the extra loop? That's the full code...

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this and see if it fixes the issue:

```
public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> Traverse()
{
foreach (var node in _context)
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
    if(!node.HasChildren) {
     yield return node;
    }
    else {
    foreach (var child in Children().Traverse())
        yield return child;
    }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Returns c,d,e,g,h,i... which should be expected. Those nodes don't have children.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumerable<HtmlNode> All()
{
    var queue = new Queue<HtmlNode>(_context);

    while (queue.Count > 0)
    {
        var node = queue.Dequeue();
        yield return node;
        foreach (var next in node.ChildNodes.Where(n => n.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element))
            queue.Enqueue(next);
    }
}
```

[courtesy link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043050/c-performance-of-nested-yield-in-a-tree/1043363#1043363)