# Why method does not traverse entire tree

Tags: c#, linq, recursion, tree, ienumerable

I have a method that looks like:

```
    public IEnumerable<Node> TraverseTree(Node root)
    {            
        if(root.Children != null)
        {
            foreach(var item in root.Children)
                TraverseTree(item);
        }

        yield return root;
    }
```

and when I do:

```
var allItems = TraverseTree(someRootNode).ToList();
```

I only get the first node. Is it not possible to use recursion when using IEnumerable? It will be nice if I can use IEnumerable so that my linq queries do not fully execute.

### Edit

Sorry my Node class looks like:

```
class Node
{
     public Node Val;
     public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
}
```

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830174/how-to-flatten-tree-via-linq

Comment: I found a similar solution at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1043363/637142  I like aquaraga solution better though ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be rewritten as:

```
    public IEnumerable<Node> TraverseTree(Node root)
    {
        if (root.Children != null)
        {
            foreach (var child in root.Children)
            {
                var nodes = TraverseTree(child);
                foreach (var node in nodes)
                {
                    yield return node;
                }
            }
        }

        yield return root;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, with the original TraverseTree, it's not assigning the return value.