# To find subcategories using C#?

Tags: c#, .net

In an application a category can contain subcategories.  And each subcategory can contain subcategories.  A category can also be subcategories to one or more categories.  If we are given the Category class.how can we implement a property  that returns the count of UNIQUE subcategories for a category and ALL its UNIQUE subcategories?

Code Snippet

```
public class Category
{
 public List<Category> Subcategories = new List<Category>();
 public int UniqueSubcategoriesCount
 {
  get
  {
    //How to implement
    /*My Thoughts.
     1. use the CategoryID field to find the unique ones.
     2. Implement the Equals()function to   compare the CategoryID.
     3. To find the subcategories with in the categories we need to loop recursively./*
  }
 }
}
```

Any other ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Determine a uniqueness factor for each category and count the amount of distinct subcategories based on this factor. That's the best answer you can get without any code to show us.

Comment: Read about [recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) functions.

Comment: @Jeroen: Could the reference itself be ID enough? E.g. put them in a Dictionary or HashSet and then Count(). (I'm not sure whether the OP can have several instances of the same Category.)

Comment: @PeterSchneider: it's hard to answer that without knowing how the application works. If the categories themselves are simply retrieved from a central repository then this should be okay but if they are somewhere constructed then this might cause trouble. For the sake of clarity I would not rely on reference equality but always implement a correct value equality.

Comment: Is it possible to have a circular reference between two or more categories?

Comment: You want the transitive nonreflexive closure of the subcategory relation, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understand from your question, you could try something like this:

```
//Category implementation
public class Category
{
    public List<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public static int count = 0;

    public Category()
    {
        SubCategories = new List<Category>();
    }

    public void Add(Category cat)
    {
        SubCategories.Add(cat);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Category> AllSubCategories()
    {
        var stack = new Stack<Category>();
        stack.Push(this);

        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            Category cat = stack.Pop();
            yield return cat;

            foreach (Category nextCat in cat.SubCategories)
                stack.Push(nextCat);
        }

    }

}

...

//Testing the code
Category top = new Category() { CategoryID = 1 };
top.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 2 });
top.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 5 });
top.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 3 });
top.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 1 });
top.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 2 });
top.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 4 });

Category tmp = new Category() { CategoryID = 1 };
top.Add(tmp);

tmp.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 1 });
tmp.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 7 });
tmp.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = 6 });

Category tmp2 = new Category() { CategoryID = 7 };
tmp.Add(tmp2);

Category tmp3 = new Category() { CategoryID = 4 };
tmp2.Add(tmp3);

Category tmp4 = new Category() { CategoryID = 3 };
tmp3.Add(tmp4);

Category tmp5 = new Category() { CategoryID = 1 };
tmp4.Add(tmp5);

Category tmp6 = new Category() { CategoryID = 9 };
tmp5.Add(tmp6);

var Result = top.AllSubCategories().GroupBy(c => c.CategoryID).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Cheers

EDIT #1: I think I should give credit to Jon Skeet for this idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2055946/172769

Just in case anyone is wondering where it came from.

EDIT #2: Based on comments from Eric Lippert about bad performace of nested iterators, I changed my code to use an "unwind to stack" method that I got from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043363/172769

Comment: Note that this solution is worst case quadratic in time and linear in stack. You can make it linear in time and heap, constant in stack

Comment: @EricLippert I know you mean well, but I have no clue what you're talking about. It would certainly benefit me (and others), if you could provide an example, maybe your own version of the solution, and explain how each of your affirmations is demonstrated by your example.

Comment: See Wes dyers article on nested iterator blocks for a good analysis.

Comment: Briefly: suppose the subcategory tree is deep but not broad. Count how many times you yield something. Do you see the relationship between depth and number of yields?

Comment: @EricLippert I find that when deepening the levels, without broadening them (each level having 1 item), I get n(n+1)/2 yields. I understand on the surface, but it hasn't sunken in yet. I must read some more to understand the inner workings of this.

Comment: Right, that's why it is in the worst case quadratic in time.

Comment: @EricLippert please comment my new attempt.

Comment: You got it; that's now worst case linear in heap because the explicit stack is now being used instead of the call stack. And the number of yields is equal to the number of items yielded, so it is linear in time.  The downside is of course that the code is longer and less elegant. C-Omega would automatically rewrite nested iterators into the more efficient form but that feature was never added to C#.

Comment: @EricLippert it's stuff like this that make me realize how little I really know about formal programming.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID;
    public List<Category> Subcategories = new List<Category>();
    public int UniqueSubcategoriesCount
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetUniqueSubcategories().Count();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Category> GetUniqueSubcategories()
    {
        return
            this
                .GetSubcategories()
                .ToLookup(x => x.CategoryID)
                .SelectMany(xs => xs.Take(1));
    }

    private IEnumerable<Category> GetSubcategories()
    {
        return this.Subcategories
            .Concat(this.Subcategories
                .SelectMany(x => x.GetSubcategories()));
    }
}
```